# Find ONLY results that have associated children in Seqeualize

Tags: sequelize.js

In Seqeualize, I have a model A, that has children from model B - `A.hasMany(B)`.
I want to find all rows from A, that HAVE children from B.
Something like this:

```
A.findAll({
    where: {
        'bs.length': { [Op.gt]: 0 },
    },
    include: {
        model: B,
        as: 'bs',
    },
});
```

Obviously, this query is not working. Any suggestions?

Comment: Of course, im reffering only for using Eager Loading :)

Answer (score 0):

This is a tweaked version of the code you have tried basically you have to refer the child column in parent via `{'$child$':{[Op.gt]>0}` also to remove all the columns to get only parent's attributes.

```
A.findAll({haveIt]],
    attributes: [[literal('count(bs.id)'), 'haveIt]],
    having: {
        haveIt: { [Op.gt]: 0 },
    },
    include: [{
        model: B,
        as: 'bs',
        attributes: []
    }],
});
```

also, check out the where function which when collab with col() gets the desired values at times.

> Official Docs:
> [https://sequelize.org/master/class/lib/sequelize.js~Sequelize.html#static-method-where](https://sequelize.org/master/class/lib/sequelize.js%7ESequelize.html#static-method-where)

Comment: That gives me an error: "DatabaseError [SequelizeDatabaseError]: missing FROM-clause entry for table "count(bs""

Comment: check it now and you can fiddle around the answer and the docs a bit.